# mysql another way of using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing some time matching but it takes too much time.

Example i have

TABLE aaa

```
id | emp_id|shift_in               | shift_out             | actual_timein | actual_timout 
1  | 123   | "2014-10-11 01:00:00" | "2014-10-11 01:00:00" | null          | null
```

TABLE bbb  status 0=out : 1=in

```
id| emp_id | status | timelog | 
1 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-11 01:03:00"
2 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-11 00:48:00"
3 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-10 21:14:00"
4 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-10 23:47:00"
1 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-11 08:01:00"
1 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-11 08:02:00"
1 | 123    | 1      |  "2014-10-11 08:03:00"
```

what im doing is updating the table bbb 
`actual_timein` first then another statement for `actual_timeout`

```
UPDATE aaa c
  INNER JOIN(
      select *, MIN(time_log) as my_time from aaa w
         inner join bbb b on b.emp_id = a.emp_id and status = 1
and time_log < shift_in and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.shift_in, b.time_log))/3600  < 2
where b.timelog between '2014-10-01' and  '2014-10-31'
group by a.emp_id order by b.timelog asc
    ) d on d.emp_id = c.emp_id 
set c.actual_timein = d.my_time
```

assuming that the code works :) .... 
any other way to do this? 
 
if i have 200 employee it will have 3000 in table aaa per 15days with schedule  200*15

 thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
UPDATE aaa c INNER JOIN
       (select *, MIN(time_log) as my_time
        from aaa w inner join
             bbb b
             on b.emp_id = a.emp_id and b.status = 1 and time_log < shift_in and 
                TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.shift_in, b.time_log))/3600  < 2
        where b.timelog between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31'
        group by a.emp_id
        order by b.timelog asc
      ) d
      on d.emp_id = c.emp_id 
    set c.actual_timein = d.my_time;
```

Initial observations:  the `*` is unnecessary (and unwise in an aggregation query).  The `order by` is unnecessary.  So, try this version:

```
UPDATE aaa c INNER JOIN
       (select a.emp_id MIN(time_log) as my_time
        from aaa w inner join
             bbb b
             on b.emp_id = a.emp_id and b.status = 1 and b.time_log < shift_in and 
                TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(a.shift_in, b.time_log))/3600  < 2
        where b.timelog between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-31'
        group by a.emp_id
      ) d
      on d.emp_id = c.emp_id 
    set c.actual_timein = d.my_time;
```

Second, indexes can probably help.  I would suggest `bbb(status, time_log, emp_id)` for the inner query.

Comment: the "*" is my bad and order is unnecessary too because MIN(), ** indexes can probably help... i forget about this thanks... THANKS ^_^